# Call sas program in a loop

Tags: sas

I have a SAS program . I need to call the SAS program multiple times, each time passing a different date parameter.
Am I correct that first I need to wrap the entire .sas file into some kind of macro and then I need to call that macro repeatedly? Or is there a way to do it without wrapping it in a macro ?

Comment: It depends on what you have to do with a loop. If it is something to repeat within a dataset you can probably do it with a loop without macro. If you need to repeadt data spteps, procedures... then yes you have to do it with a macro. I recommend you to post an example of your code, showing what you need to do with a short dataset and your expected result.

Comment: https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Turning%20a%20program%20into%20a%20macro.md

Comment: See the tutorial above about converting a program into a macro. If you follow the steps outlined, you're also less likely to run into any issues with the conversion.

Comment: How are you planning to call the program repeatedly?  Are you planning to run this by hand several times, say once per day?  Are you running this from windows scheduler and need it to pick up the date?  Or are you going to open SAS, and want to run the whole thing for 5 different dates?  Where do those dates come from?

Comment: Please edit your question to show an example of the type of program you have, and how you want call it in a loop.  The macro language is one common way to invoke a sas program in a loop, but there are plenty of alternatives worth considering.  As is, your question is too broad to be answerable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: maybe, yes.

**Maybe:**

If you have specific program you wish to launch each time with certain parameter that can be done from command line. There is `sysparm`-variable, which is imported to the program, like following:

```
> <path>SASHome\SASFoundation\9.4\sas.exe -sysparm "21537"
```

which in SAS code is equivalent to:

```
%let sysparm = 21537;
```

This enables you to restrict, label data wit your input as much need be. Also you can run your program as many times with any parameter you wish. What we do is parse the Sysparm to allow multiple parameter to be passed.

[For more on Sysparm, see documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0u0t8c3b3syeen1l1rqh60ekmfz.htm)

**Yes:**

If you want to run your code mulitple times in a session you ideally want something like:

```
 %macro do_stuff(your_date):
    %put Processing date &your_date.; 

    data data_&your_date.; 
      set someLib.begin; 
      if your_date < data_date < (your_date-20) ; 
    run;
    /*And so forth....*/
 %mend do_stuff; 

 %do_stuff(date_1);
 %do_stuff(date_2);
 %do_stuff(date_3);
```